# IDA Pro Dump of instructions and offsets

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin, plugin

I'm writing a plugin for IDA PRO with IDAPython and I need to make a dump of the full disassembled code with offsets.

I know I can export a html file and then parse it but I cannot call the GenerateFile function with the GENFLG_GENHTML flag from the script since that function only works from the gui

```
idc.GenerateFile(OFILE_LST, idc.GetInputFile()+'.html', 0, idc.BADADDR, GENFLG_GENHTML)
```

(when I run the plugin it gives me unhandled exception but if I write the same instruction from the IDA command line it works).

I can extract the .asm file but it is not useful to me because it does not contain the offsets. Are there any solutions?

Comment: Do you need an HTML, or just offsets and the ASM?

Comment: Also, what versions of IDA and IDAPython are you using?

Comment: @tmr232 I need the full disassembly with the offsets, the output format is not important as long i can parse it. I'm using IDA 6.6

Answer (score 1):

You're currently passing a string as the second argument to [`GenerateFile()`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/244.shtml), but the second argument needs to be a file handle.

Comment: But that same function called from IDA command line works perfecly...

Comment: That sounds like a nice feature offered by the GUI. However, to use the function from a script you should follow the correct calling convention.

Comment: So what shoud I do? Create/open a file f = open("file.html", "w") and then use f in GenerateFile?

Comment: Use [`fopen()`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/314.shtml).

Comment: It doesn't work: it is deprecated

GenerateFile(OFILE_LST, fopen('file.html', 'w+'), 0, idc.BADADDR, GENFLG_GENHTML)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\IDA 6.6\python\idc.py", line 3907, in fopen
    raise DeprecatedIDCError, "fopen() deprecated. Use Python file objects instead."
idc.DeprecatedIDCError: fopen() deprecated. Use Python file objects instead.

Comment: Great, looks like you can use Python's `open()` function then.

Comment: Nope. if I use GenerateFile(OFILE_LST, open('file.html', 'w+'), 0, idc.BADADDR, GENFLG_GENHTML) i get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\IDA 6.6\python\idc.py", line 1571, in GenerateFile
    f = idaapi.fopenWT(path)
  File "C:\Program Files\IDA 6.6\python\idaapi.py", line 25300, in fopenWT
    return _idaapi.fopenWT(*args)
TypeError: in method 'fopenWT', argument 1 of type 'char const *'

It seems to be a problem with the wrapper...

Comment: Probably best to email support@hex-rays.com then.